# XML file not overwriting on that other server computer

Tags: javascript, php, xml

The php script runs perfectly well on xampp localhost. I'm stuck and out of ideas. Any help why this doesn't work on seve r(the XML file isn't updated without the removed nodes) would be appreciated:

I'm doing some javascript and I want to use PHP to change something in XML file on the server. I have 4 .php scripts 2 for adding nodes and 2 for removing. I'm using XMLHTTP to run those scripts. Those with adding are running correctly but those 2 for removing are not. I use exactly the same method to run those scripts so I think it's not the matter.

This is how i run the php script from javascript

```
function removeFloor(){
var param=selectedId+"!"+0;
var grid=document.getElementById(selectedId);
//RUN PHP SCRIPT
var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                //do something
                }
            }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","removeFloor.php?q="+param,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your server-logs for error-messages? Most likely there is something wrong with the file-permissions (if this script does work on your localhost)

Comment: have you taken a look at the folder rights? which user owns the folder? are you getting any error messages? Maybe there aren't enough rights to write on that folder.

Comment: Well, but two scripts which add nodes work correctly and overwrite the same file.

Comment: And what did your error-log say?

Comment: To be honest i don't think i can check it. I only have an opened workspace on the server where i put and run all the scripts.

Comment: If something does not work, next step is to find out what still works. So which part of that script in your server still works? Please reduce code and question on stackoverflow only to the concrete question, not to the total amount of all side-effects. E.g. the side-effect of switching hosts. It's about *programming* questions. And another rule is: Do not post excerpts of your live-code. Instead re-write the example from scratch to demonstrate the issue by reproducing it. Use as little code as necessary for the demonstration. Make it self-contained.